# Letting layout controls appear in a UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, user-controls

I am trying to write a `UserControl` that will allow both single controls in it (like `Label`), as well as "layout" controls like `StackPanel` and friends.

I am having trouble doing that. The code I have works for single controls, but not for layout controls. I have a feeling this is an obvious fix, I am new to WPF. Here is the `UserControl` XAML:

```
<UserControl <!-- namespaces omitted for brevity -->>
    <UserControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.ContentTemplate>
</UserControl>
```

When I try to use it like this:

```
<my:SpecialUserControl>
    hello
</my:SpecialUserControl>
```

It's fine. But when I try to do something like

```
<my:SpecialUserControl>
    <StackPanel>
        <!-- stuff -->
    </StackPanel>
</my:SpecialUserControl>
```

I get an error in Visual Studio Intellisense saying

> The specified value cannot be assigned to the collection. The following type was expected: `UIElement`

And when I run the app (it builds), I get this exception at that place in the XAML:

> 'Add value to collection of type `System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection` threw an exception.' Line number `x` and line position `y`.

What can I do to make my `UserControl` able to accept any type of content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ContentPresenter` should be a part of the **ControlTemplate** (`<UserControl.Template>`) of your control, not inside your `ContentTemplate`. I think that could be your problem.

Comment: If I do that, I get an error in `TemplateBinding Content` that says "The name `Content` is not recognized or is not accessible." If I change `TemplateBinding` to `Binding` I get no errors but the `UserControl` shows no content.

Answer (score 0):

Inherit your UserControl from `ContentControl`. `ContentControl` already has Content property combined with `ContentPresenter` inside `ControlTemplate`.

You can also use microsoft blend to get ContentControls visual tree.